# Is celery a good choice for long running tasks?

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

We are using a combination of django, rabbitmq, celery and ffmpeg to read camera streams and break them into images to be stored into filesystem. This setup works 24x7. Now, for each camera stream we are creating a separate task and each will theoretically run for indefinite period.

If a stream goes down, we wait for n number of frames, create an exception and in the exception handler, after creating a delay of 1 min using time.sleep we rerun the ffmpeg process.

My questions are,
Is this a right approach?
Should we use celery for reading streams?
Is celery the right tool to use for this task?
Can we create delay in celery task using time.sleep ? Will it affect the other tasks?

Answer (score 1):

We have relatively big Celery cluster and many of our tasks run for hours, some even run over 24 hours, so I would say yes, Celery is a good choice for long-running tasks. I know very little about audio/video processing, so I do not think there should be any problems doing it inside a Celery task. The only thing I would perhaps change in the original idea is the following: I would not sleep (yes, you can call sleep in Celery task) and continue processing, but run a new task instead. Other tasks should not be affected at all.

Comment: Could you please clarify 'but I see why Celery tasks would not be able to do what you need' ?

Comment: I phrased it badly. I rewrote that part of the sentence...